# Poedit - updated source code failed - denied permission

Tags: permission-denied, poedit

I´m using regularly Poedit to translate my Wordpress plugins.
For some reasons, now, when I click on 'Update from code', I got this error :

> Updating failed
> Permission denied
> You don´t have permission to read source code files from the location specified in the catalogue's Properties

I tried to change rights on folders and files on my OS (Windows 10) without success.
It seems to be after updated the software but I´m not sure.

Comment: Having the error to but for one particular project. Will follow the tread.

Answer (score 0):

I started having the same issue recently. After some experimentation, I figured out that the issue was that I started having some code for custom blocks in my plugin and Poedit did not like these. After adding exclusions for the `build`, `src` and `node_modules` directories, I was able to properly use the Update from code functionality.